# How to find an average of Datediff in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have set up a measure to calculate the day difference between starting date and end date, which excludes Public Holidays and Weekends.
This gives me TAT per row in a table. 
I am now trying to calculate the average of the TAT, to be placed in a separate card.
Note that some rows of the table do not have a completed date, and as such TAT is not identified, and therefore the average should not include these blanks.

I have tried to create a new measure that divides measure [TAT] by the number of [TAT], however the count function only works with columns. Have tried to create a quick measure, base value is [TAT], and catergory is [Date Finalised] (Which is a column). No luck. Below DAX codes I have tried.

```
TAT average per Date Finalised 2 = DIVIDE([TAT],COUNTROWS('Finalised'))

TAT average per Date Finalised = 
AVERAGEX(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Finalised'[Date Finalised])),
    CALCULATE([TAT])

This is how I worked out TAT
TAT = 
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        'Calendar',
        'Calendar'[Date] >= MIN ( 'Capture'[Date Captured] )
            && 'Calendar'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Finalised'[Date Finalised] ) && NOT( ISBLANK(MAX ( 'Capture'[Date Captured] )))
    ),
    'Calendar'[If work day])
```

The problem with the above functions is that they are not giving me the correct average. What my expected results are, in a table with 8 rows, but only 4 of them have an end date, with values of 29, 16, 16 and 12, the average would be (29+16+16+12)/4 which is 18.25. Instead I am getting average of 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result using the following DAX Expression:

```
TAT average per Date Finalised =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( 'Finalised'[TAT] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Finalised' ), 'Finalised'[TAT] > 0 )
)
```

**Tip:** you can also add one more filter if you need like below

```
TAT average per Date Finalised =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( 'Finalised'[TAT] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Finalised' ), 'Finalised'[TAT] > 0 ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Finalised' ), 'Finalised'[TAT] = 6 )
)
```

*the above tip is just an example of how to use more filters. It doesn't make much sense, since you can simply use one filter.*

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I am getting error "Column TAT in table Finalised cannot be found or may not be used'. Issue is that [TAT] is a measure, not a calculated column. The same DAX formula for TAT does not work correctly if placed in a calculated column.

Comment: Please check out this link for TAT as Calculated column. You might have to tweak it a little. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/counting-working-days-in-dax/